# intersection of strict transforms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Z_1,Z_2$ and $Y$ be smooth subvarieties of a smooth variety $X$. Suppose that the intersections $Z_1\cap Z_2$, $Z_1\cap Y$ and $Z_2\cap Y$ are transversal inside $X$.

Is it true that the strict transforms of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ in the blowup $Bl_YX$ intersect transversally as well?

**NB**: Two smooth subvarieties $A$ and $B$ of $X$ are said to intersect transversally- equivallently the intersection $A\cap B$ is said to be transversal in $X$- if for any $p\in A\cap B$ the tangent spaces of $A$ and $B$ at $p$ generate the tangent space of $X$ at $p$, i.e. $T_p A +T_p B= T_p X$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is correct. You could see this from writing local equations. Another way would be the following: first note that the strict transform of $Z$ is the unique closed immersion
$Bl_{Z\cap Y}Z\hookrightarrow Bl_YX$ (see [Hartshorne, Cor. II.7.15]). Since $Z\cap Y$ is smooth so is $Bl_{Z\cap Y}Z$. By a similar argument $Bl_{Z_1\cap Y}Z_1\cap Bl_{Z_2\cap Y}Z_2 = Bl_{Z_1\cap Z_2\cap Y}(Z_1\cap Z_2)$, which is smooth.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you elaborate on how to get the equality $Bl_{Z_1\cap Y}Z_1\cap Bl_{Z_2\cap Y}Z_2 = Bl_{Z_1\cap Z_2\cap Y}(Z_1\cap Z_2)$? I am not assuming that the triple intersection $Y\cap Z_1\cap Z_2$ is transversal, although I can additionally assume that it is smooth. For example if $Y$ contains $Z_1\cap Z_2$ strictly the above equality would imply that the intersection of the strict transforms of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ is empty(?)

Comment: I don't think that the equality $Bl_{Z_1\cap Y}Z_1\cap Bl_{Z_2\cap Y}Z_2 = Bl_{Z_1\cap Z_2\cap Y}(Z_1\cap Z_2)$ holds in general under the assumptions posed. For example, take $X=\mathbb{C}^2= Spec\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $Y= V(y), Z_1=V(x), Z_2=V(x-y)$.  Then, $Z_1\cap Z_2=V(x,y)$. Since the center of the blowup is a divisor nothing changes, so the strict transforms still have non trivial intersection.  However the right hand side $Bl_{Z_1\cap Z_2\cap Y}(Z_1\cap Z_2)$ becomes the blowup of the point $(0,0)$ at itself, which is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I did indeed read your question as all possible intersections are transverse, perhaps that's not necessary. Although I don't think $Y\supset Z_1\cap Z_2$ is a problem. Here blow up procedure will separate the strict transforms and hence the intersection would indeed be empty. In the example you gave, the blow-up center, i.e. the origin is not transverse to your $Z_1$ and $Z_2$. Allow me some time to flesh out the correct hypethesis under which the intersection would work the way I wrote.

Comment: In my example the blowup center $Y$ is not the origin- it is the $x$-axis and it does satisfy the transversality conditions as given in the question. As you can see the strict transforms do not get separated in that example.

Comment: @axz I see your point now. Perhaps one does need transverse intersection. Or at the very least transverse intersection of $Y$ and $Z_i$ in $Z_j$ for $i,j = 1,2$.